# Magento 2: what is datascope tag is for in ui component

Tags: xml, magento2, uicomponents

I am creating a form on the admin side with the UI component, so I want to know that is  tag is used in the field and how to add that tag in the UI component.

~ ~ thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The dataScope node allows you to change a value for the **name** attribute of your input (field), e.g.

When you use **something** as a **value** to dataScope it means your output will be like `<input name="something" ... >`

You can find more information in the following [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219692/81049)